# example of a measure with infinite dimension of hausdorff

Tags: measure-theory, fractals, dimension-theory-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\mu$ a measure of probability **non atomic** of a compact metric space $X$. The dimension de $\mu$ is $$\dim \mu=\inf\{ \dim_H(Z):\mu(Z)=1\},$$ where $\dim_H(Z)$ is the hausdorff dimension of $Z\subset X$.

I wonder if you can find an example of $\mu$ such that $\dim \mu=\infty$ ?

Comment: The only sets of extended real numbers with an infimum of $\infty$ are $\emptyset$ and $\{ \infty \}$.

Comment: Consider the product measure on the Hilbert cube.